# Optimize writing of each pandas row to a different .txt

Tags: python, pandas, parallel-processing

### Problem

I am dealing with a `df` with two columns: `'body'` and `'label'`. I need to write each row's `'body'` to a different .txt. Currently I am doing that by iterating over the rows and writing them with python's file IO manager, but it's becoming too slow as the number of rows I'm dealing with is increasing..

Below, how the actual code is: (The number of the row **MUST** be the filename!)

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    with open(path+str(index)+".txt", "w+", encoding="utf-8") as f:
        f.write(row['body'])
```

I believe there is a better way of doing that, I'm just not sure what it is.

---

### Progress

I am already using `pandarallel` but didn't manage to use a lambda function over the rows in such a way that the index of the row is captured and sent to the aux function.

```
def writer_aux(body_text, index):
    with open(path+str(index)+".txt", "w+", encoding="utf-8") as f:
        f.write(body_text)

df['body'].parallel_apply(lambda x: writer_aux(x,x.index)) # something like that
```

Can someone help me with either a suggestion to make the lambda capture the row index or another way to do this writing more efficiently? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to achieve a significant increase in performance using Python's `multiprocessing`. Here's how I did it (read the code as if you were reading a Jupyter Notebook):

Let's start by importing the required modules:

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd
        from timeit import default_timer as timer
        import multiprocessing as mp
        import uuid
```

Simulating your data:

```
In [2]: num_rows = 250000
        num_hex = 100

        df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({
            "label": [f"Some label {i}" for i in range(num_rows)],
            "body": ["".join([uuid.uuid4().hex for _ in range(num_hex)])
                     for _ in range(num_rows)]
        })

        df

Out [2]:

        label                          body
0   Some label 0    594a41b8960d4856871efef2ea39d39812ec046f175343...
1   Some label 1    9561a81d063b41298e27b079fb180e2fbaaad3768ace4b...
2   Some label 2    fabc1604c6494d56bfb7878ad5859f68a2a6f294946046...
3   Some label 3    e8aabab1ddc04b5aab1050aec7873bb3f0deec79af9e41...
4   Some label 4    08c70b7121c047838d41d6312417ea40827558b0b74342...
... ... ...
249995  Some label 249995   69ba44d138b04b0497d2457f89a54ea95ef7330fb44745...
249996  Some label 249996   4466820a1a634ff59fa3a544c7623fc27caaf1f04a264c...
249997  Some label 249997   f03d2e7087964e5f8fdb74e4799535be740f48937c4c43...
249998  Some label 249998   41dfeb037f9f44789024b766bfb864ee2bc05e9c50aa49...
249999  Some label 249999   2aa84b40276443b98a588c9677713769d2b756398d1f46...

250000 rows × 2 columns
```

Here's the function we'll use to write the rows to a `.txt` file:

```
In [3]: def row2txt(idx, out_path="./out"):
            row = df.iloc[idx]
            file_name = f"{out_path}/row{idx}.txt"
            with open(file_name, "w+", encoding="utf-8") as f:
                f.write(row['body'])
```

Now, let's try the "naive" method and see how well it does:

```
In [4]: # SEQUENTIAL
        start_time = timer()
        for idx in range(len(df)):
            row2txt(idx)
        print(f"[SEQUENTIAL] Elapsed time: {timer() - start_time}s")

Out [4]: [SEQUENTIAL] Elapsed time: 26.99295247200007s
```

Now, let's use Python's `multiprocessing`:

```
In [5]: # PARALLEL
        start_time = timer()
        with mp.Pool() as pool:
            pool.map(row2txt, [idx for idx in range(len(df))])
        print(f"[PARALLEL] Elapsed time: {timer() - start_time}s")

Out [5]: [PARALLEL] Elapsed time: 4.735888680999778s
```

As you can see, the parallelized approach is 5.7x faster than the sequential one! The more CPU cores your machine has, the greater should be the difference between the two approaches. The machine on which I ran the tests has 6 cores (12 when you consider hyper-threading).

[Link](https://gist.github.com/Talendar/823790a6d07c7a097a6e49125c7bc669) to the code (GitHub). You can also run it on Google Colab.

Comment: Are you on an SSD and have lots of RAM? Using 50,000 rows; on old hardware with an HDD, sequential was 242 secs (4mins 2secs) vs parallel's ...well, it's still running 18 minutes later, and not yet done. So **parallel was actually _slower_**. Nevertheless, this is a better & more thorough answer. +1

Comment: @aneroid Thank you for your reply! Yes, the machine in which I ran the tests have a SSD and lots of RAM. This probably have a great impact on how fast each of the approaches runs. I did test this on Google Colab, though, and was able to get a 1.5x faster execution with the parallelized approach ([link](https://colab.research.google.com/gist/Talendar/823790a6d07c7a097a6e49125c7bc669/pandas_parallel.ipynb) to the notebook).

Answer (score 1):

This won't get faster in a meaningful way. Even if `parallel_apply` does operate in parallel, you're not gaining much because the slowness comes from the **File I/O**, not the iteration.

If you were writing all the rows to the *same* file (and not a new file for each row), then there could be some speedup through buffering but that's still much slower than pure iteration.

---

If `parallel_apply` works the same way as [`df.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) (but in parallel), that last line

```py
df['body'].parallel_apply(lambda x: writer_aux(x,x.index))
```

should be

```py
df.parallel_apply(lambda x: writer_aux(x['body'], x.name), axis=1)
```

(When you do `df['body'].apply(...)`, only the 'body' is passed to the function in apply, not the index. So `x.index` would be the [`str.index()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.index) method of the body text, and not the index of the row.)

You could also do:

```py
df[['body']].apply(lambda x: writer_aux(x, x.name), axis=1)
# note the double brackets around 'body'
```

Comment: with `df.parallel_apply(lambda x: writer_aux(x['body'], x.index), axis=1)` x.index actually returns the column names, not the actual integer index of the row being passed to `writer_aux` which is what I want. How to fix that?

Comment: That was an error, should be `x.name`; fixed it. Also, your edit on my answer should be a comment, not an edit :-)